# Why is blocking callstack considered bad practice in RxJava?

Tags: rx-java

The Backpressure Documentation [states](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Backpressure#callstack-blocking-as-a-flow-control-alternative-to-backpressure)

> Another way of handling an overproductive Observable is to block the callstack (parking the thread that governs the overproductive Observable). This has the disadvantage of going against the “reactive” and non-blocking model of Rx.

Could anyone elaborate why this is considered bad practice? References appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you may end up blocking a thread, for example, the `computation()` Scheduler, preventing some or all progress of other streams. The second problem is that backpressure and blocking/unblocking doesn't play nice with each other. This was a problem with the now removed `onBackpressureBlock` where a chain with `subscribeOn().onBackpressureBlock()` worked but `onBackpressureBlock().subscribeOn()` deadlocked.

Unless you have to deal with legacy blocking IO or API, there is almost always a way to perform things non-blockingly.